# Как обозначить символу значение к примеру деление питон?

Tags: python

К примеру у нас есть символ ":" и нам нужно поставить ему задачю выполнять действие деления. вот немного похожий код который у меня провалился но он легко понятен ":"=(//). У меня на этот код выводит ошибку хотя по операторам я делаю все правильно.Почему он видит ошибку и как это исправить? Я новенький по питону так что не осуждайте за не знание.

Comment: Вы не можете сказать компилятору Питона: "Вот символ ':', я хочу чтобы ты делил когда встретишь его в коде". Этого просто нет в данном языке. В некоторых других есть, а в этом нет.

Comment: Но вы можете написать на Питоне интерпретатор (строковый калькулятор), который будет делить числа по знаку ':'. Это классическая учебная задача, хоть и не самая простая.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через условия, если введённые пользователем данные равняются ':', то x // y